# Python: How to update list with two elements

Tags: python

I have a list:

[['salt', 1],['milk', 2],['orange', 2],['eggs', 5]]

I want to add quantity to an item at a time, how can I do that?

Say firstly, I want to add 3 oranges, so list will look like:

[['salt', 1],['milk', 2],['orange', 5],['eggs', 5]]

Next, I want to add 1 milk, so list will look like:

[['salt', 1],['milk', 3],['orange', 5],['eggs', 5]]

Lastly, I want to reduce 2 eggs, so list will look like:

[['salt', 1],['milk', 3],['orange', 5],['eggs', 3]]

Comment: With a list, you can have multiple items, e.g. `[['milk', 2], ['milk', 1]]`. With a dictionary, you can only have one key value.  Which structure you use depends on your use case.

Comment: Then you are probably better of with the dictionary solution below as proposed by @TigerhawkT3.

Answer (score 5):

Using a dictionary will make your life much easier. First create it out of what I assume is an existing `list`:

```
l = [['salt', 1],['milk', 2],['orange', 2],['eggs', 5]]
d = dict(l)
```

Or use a dictionary literal:

```
d = {'orange': 2, 'eggs': 5, 'salt': 1, 'milk': 2}
```

Either of these will create a dictionary `d`:

```
{'orange': 2, 'eggs': 5, 'salt': 1, 'milk': 2}
```

And then you can modify it:

```
d['orange'] += 3
d['milk'] += 1
d['eggs'] -= 3
```

The result is as follows:

```
{'orange': 5, 'eggs': 2, 'salt': 1, 'milk': 3}
```